# Div not showing up in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing the odin project and for the front-end webdev project, I have to create a grid using javascript/jQuery. I tried using the createElement method but I was wondering how I would be able to make the div visible in html? 
Am I going about this all wrong?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="etch-a-sketch.css">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type = "text/javascript" src="etch-a-sketch.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>


    </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.color = "blue";

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: you haven't set background color

Comment: Are you getting some error?...you didn't write anything in the div, try div.innerHTML = 'hi';

Comment: I'm not too sure how to run the code

Answer (score 2):

Add `background-color`

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.color = "blue";

div.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";//you forgot background color

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: I added background color but am I link tagging the javascript correcting in my html? how would I run this in Sublime Text 2?

Answer (score 1):

Add more styling to make it visible, such as a border or background color.

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.color = "blue";
div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

document.body.appendChild(div);
```